# How will the Mars One landing site be chosen?

Tags: mars, landing, mars-one, planning, site-selection

How is Mars One planning on choosing a landing site? Will they be able to use NASA assets (Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter, etc) to assist with choosing a site, or will they have to make do with public sources?

Comment: I'm not sure how Mars One is choosing a landing site, but most sites are chosen using some form of Multi-Criteria Analysis using GIS.  Please see the [similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/66371/7424) I asked (and answered) regarding the Curiosity landing site on GIS.SE.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Mars One](http://www.sen.com/feature/mars-one-plans-for-human-settlement-on-mars.html) Website:

> According to the Mars One roadmap, a demonstration mission carrying
>   proof of concept for some of the technologies and a communication
>   satellite would be launched in January 2016. The communication
>   satellite would arrive in orbit in October 2016 and would be able to
>   relay images and videos from the surface of the Red Planet back to
>   Earth.
>
> The first settlement rover should arrive on the Red Planet in 2018,
>   tasked to find the right location to establish the Martian village.
>   Mission planners believe that the idea settlement site would be far
>   enough north for the soil to contain water, equatorial enough for
>   maximum solar power and flat enough for construction of the village.
>   Once the ideal site is located, the rover would prepare the ground for
>   the arrival of cargo supplies.

Bottom line is, a launch in 2016 to scout out potential areas to land will happen, followed by a settlement rover to better determine a landing spot, and finally cargo supplies will be sent out ahead of time. I strongly suspect that publicly available data will assist in landing site selection, and perhaps they will even use the [HiWish](http://www.uahirise.org/hiwish/) system to request a few images, but as a whole, it seems like they are prepared to launch their own equipment to determine their landing site.